# How can I update Tkinter label text before running next line of code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to tell user in the label  that the file is being processed before actually running the ImageSync process. But for some reason, the ImageSync starts before the label gets created and visible, and label only becomes visible after ImageSync process completes.

I want to inform the user that the process has begun before it actually begins.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import ImageSync

window = Tk() #tkinter window instance
window.title("Invoice Pics")
window.geometry('720x500')

lblInfo = Label(window, text = 'Explanation')
lblInfo.pack()



def selectFolder():
    invoice = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    lbl = Label(window, text='Processing file: ' + invoice)
    lbl.pack()

    ImageSync.main(invoice)
    


btn2 = Button(window, text = 'Select file.', \
              command = selectFolder)
btn2.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because tkinter mainloop does not take back the control when `ImageSync.main(invoice)` is being executed and so the label cannot be updated.  Add `lbl.update()` after `lbl.pack()` to force update.

Comment: Perfect answer....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add lbl.update() after lbl.pack() to force update. – acw1668